# How to configure id-token-hint when using UserFlows (logout redirect)?

Tags: azure, azure-ad-b2c

We want to configure a secure login redirect and followed the instructions in the documentation [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/session-behavior?pivots=b2c-user-flow), section *To require an ID Token in logout requests*. But when running our Web app we getting an error indicating that we miss an *id-token-hint*. The documentation [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/id-token-hint?source=recommendations) explains what to do in the case of Custom Policies. But how can we configure this using UserFlows and the Microsoft.Identity.Web package?

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass last valid id token i.e id_token_hint that existed prior to the logout.

In the user flow you can set the id_token_hint in the properties as mentioned below:

[image]

Comment: any information on how to pass last valid id token i.e id_token_hint for blazor .net application?